# How to add Signals to objects created with add_child

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm looking to create child objects that are duplicates of a pre-existing, using this method in my root class. While it successfully creates a copy of that object in the remote tree during runtime, it is not sending signals like the original object (for instance, the objects send a signal to a UI component which displays its global position in realtime). How do I create a child object that matches the signals emitted by the original?

func create_Object(Obj, size, position):
var New = Obj.instance()
add_child(New)
New.scale = size
New.global_transform.origin = position

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the lists of defined signals of a `Node` with `get_signal_list`. Example:

```
var signals = node.get_signal_list()
for cur_signal in signals:
    print(cur_signal.name)
```

You can use `get_signal_connection_list` to get the outgoing connections:

```
var signals = node.get_signal_list()
for cur_signal in signals:
    var conns = node.get_signal_connection_list(cur_signal.name)
    for cur_conn in conns:
        print(cur_conn.signal)
        print(cur_conn.target)
        print(cur_conn.method)
```

Then connect them with, well, `connect`:

```
var signals = node.get_signal_list()
for cur_signal in signals:
    var conns = node.get_signal_connection_list(cur_signal.name)
    for cur_conn in conns:
        new_node.connect(cur_conn.signal, cur_conn.target, cur_conn.method)
```