# Is it possible to create a button factory with buttons these emit signal by pressed?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I want to create a button factory that creates buttons by a specific configuration as parameters. The button have to emit a signal if there is pressed. I can't find any method to add that functionality programatically.
I know, that i can add buttons by the editor and add that function to it by a script. But with a factory, i don't need to add every button by my self.

Big thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[`Button`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_basebutton.html)s emit a signal when they are pressed, it is called [`"pressed"`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_basebutton.html#class-basebutton-signal-pressed). That is not a functionality you need to add.**

*Perhaps what you need is something else? The Godot editor is built on the same API as your game, so you can do from code virtually anything the editor can do… such as…*

---

**You can add a script from code**

If you need to add a signal, the usual way is to attach a script that has the signal declared and the logic to emit it.

If you have such script created, you can [`load`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_@gdscript.html#class-gdscript-method-load) or [`preload`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_@gdscript.html#class-gdscript-method-preload) it in your code, and then attach the script to the [`Object`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html) you want (with [`set_script`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-set-script)). *There is also a [`get_script`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-get-script) method to retrieve it. And a [`"script_changed"`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-signal-script-changed).*

And yes, you can create scripts from code too. Create a [`GDScript`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_gdscript.html) object, set its [`source_code`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_script.html#class-script-property-source-code), and [`reload`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_script.html#class-script-method-reload) it. Then you can attach it to an `Object` just as if you had loaded it.

*By the way, the script is a `Resource` which is why you can `load` it or `preload` it. See also [`ResourceLoader`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_resourceloader.html). It also means that you can save it with [`ResourceSaver`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_resourcesaver.html). However, I remind that [resource paths](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/filesystem.html#resource-path) aren't always writable.*

---

**You can add signals from code**

Yes, you can add dynamically signals from code. *I mean custom signals that are not declared in a script, and that could be added at any moment.* To do that you call [`add_user_signal`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-add-user-signal) on the `Object`. *You can check with [`has_user_signal`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-has-user-signal) (use [`has_signal`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html?#class-object-method-has-signal) if you don't care if it was added with `add_user_signal` or not). And no, there is no remove method for these. So use these sparingly and with intent.*

By the way, you can get an [`Array`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_array.html) of all signals on an object with [`get_signal_list`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-get-signal-list).

---

**You can emit signals from code**

You do that you can call [`emit_signal`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-emit-signal).

And you can call it on other objects too (I mean, you don't have to call `emit_signal` from an script attached to the `Object` that has the signal, it can be from a different one).

---

**You can manage connections from code**

I also remind you that you can connect a signal with the [`connect`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-connect) method. See also [`disconnect`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-disconnect) and [`is_connected`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-is-connected).

Oh, and you can query the connections with [`get_incoming_connections`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-get-incoming-connections) and [`get_signal_connection_list`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-get-signal-connection-list) (Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65831942/402022), it also demonstrates `get_signal_list`). No, you don't need to worry about disconnecting the signals when freeing the object. Godot takes care of that.

---

**And you can block signals too**

You can have an object block its signals with [`set_block_signals`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-set-block-signals), and check with [`is_blocking_signals`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-is-blocking-signals). *I - personally - haven't used this, never had the necessity. I just mentioning it for completeness sake.*